# Для чего объявляется статическое поле типа этого же класса?

Tags: ооп, typescript

Пока слабо знаком с TypeScript, но вот с таким ни в одном языке пока не приходилось встречаться, увидел данный код в бойлерплейте ASP.NET Core + React-Redux + TS. Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем нужно объявлять статическое поле того же типа, в описании которого оно и объявляется?

```
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { BaseService } from './base.service';
import { IAuthUser, ICredentials } from '../store/auth/types';

/**
 * Auth API abstraction layer communication via Axios (typescript singleton pattern)
 */
class AuthService extends BaseService {
  private static _authService: AuthService; // вот эта строка
  private static _controllerName: string = 'Auth';

  private constructor(controllerName: string) {
    super(controllerName);
  }

  public static get Instance(): AuthService {
    return this._authService || (this._authService = new this(this._controllerName));
  }

  public async logoutAsync(): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
    return await this.$http.post('Logout');
  }

  public async loginAsync(credentials: ICredentials): Promise<IAuthUser> {
    const { data } = await this.$http.post<IAuthUser>('Login', credentials);
    return data;
  }
}

export const AuthApi = AuthService.Instance;
```

Comment: Singleton думаю

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Не заметил в комментариях написано же singleton. А почему Статик. Эт чтоб гарантировать только один экземпляр класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кусочек [отсюда](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

> Одиночка (англ. Singleton) — порождающий шаблон проектирования,
> гарантирующий, что в однопоточном приложении будет единственный
> экземпляр некоторого класса, и предоставляющий глобальную точку
> доступа к этому экземпляру.

Comment: Благодарю! И правда, синглтон. Просто смутило, не вызывает ли такое объявление ошибки или рекурсию какую-то.